# How to use the fetch function in javascript to respond to HTTP 400 and 200?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am trying to use the `fetch` method in javascript to post data to the server.

Here is what I have done

```
var formData = {};// data
var url = ''; // url
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(formData)
}).then(async response => {

    addClientFormAlert.innerHTML = '';
    addClientFormAlert.classList.add('d-none');

    if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.json();
    }
     
    var data = await response.json();

    Object.values(data.errors).forEach(function (items) {

        if (items.errorMessage) {
            addClientFormAlert.innerHTML += '<p>' + items.errorMessage + '</p>';
        } else {
            items.forEach(function (item) {
                addClientFormAlert.innerHTML += '<p>' + item + '</p>';
            });
        }
    });

    addClientFormAlert.classList.remove('d-none');

}).then(client => function () {
    // This should only be called when the request returns HTTP code 200
    console.log('Request completed and here is the new client...', client);
});
```

But the second `then` never gets called even when the server return HTTP code 200.

How can I correctly use the `fetch` function to post data and capture HTTP code 200 and/or 400?

Comment: There's a missing `await` on `return response.json();`

Comment: @Phix that did not change the outcome. the second `then` never gets called and I get not errors in the console

Comment: You need to return something from the first then

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the syntax.
The line `}).then(client => function () {` should be `}).then(client => () {` now that works